# How to save collapse status in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I collapse some codes in Notepad++ and click Save button to save my code,then exit.
After I reload my file, I find all my codes is not collapse, how to save collapse status in Notepad++ ? Thanks!

Comment: partial answer: http://superuser.com/questions/365246/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-code-folding-in-notepad

:D hope thats good enough for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems  that such property was not yet developed but you can vote for it in the [notepad-plus: IdeaTorrent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/236/). Consider using `View->Fold All` meanwhile...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve this one time in the past, I discovered there is no method to save collapsed code status. I have since moved on to using Netbeans for the languages I work in and have not regretted it.

I would suggest collapsed state saving is something only necessary in larger coding projects, in which case it's probably not perfectly suited (thus why this has not yet been implemented).